# How to make NumPy print trailing 0s?

Tags: python, numpy, formatting, string-formatting

When printing arrays, Numpy replaces trailing `0`s with s, *e.g.*

```
[-0.678231 -0.618304 -0.6077    0.014845]
```

How can I fix this and make it print the `0`s?

Comment: Also, I wonder why the developers thought this was a good default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use numpy's [`set_printoptions`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html#numpy.set_printoptions) with a custom formatter to set the precision and exact format of the output; for your case,

```
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': '{: 0.3f}'.format})
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Sadly, the printed number will not be lined up in the decimal separator